# How do I list all AWS S3 objects that are public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wanted to list all the objects that are in my s3 buckets that are public. Using the get-object-acl would list the grantees for a specific object so I was wondering if there are better options

Comment: Also, note the objects can be "public" via a Bucket Policy in addition to the object-specific ACL.

Answer (score 3):

Relying on `get-object-acl` is probably not what you want to do, because objects can be made public by means other than their ACL. At the very least, this is possible through both the object's ACL and also the bucket's policy (see e.g. https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/how-allow-public-access-amazon-bucket/), and perhaps there are other means I don't know about.

A smarter test is to make a HEAD request to each object with no credentials. If you get a 200, it's public. If you get a 403, it's not.

The steps, then, are:

1. Get a list of buckets with the [ListBuckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html) endpoint. From the CLI, this is:

   ```
   aws2 s3api list-buckets
   ```
2. For each bucket, get its region and list its objects. From the CLI (assuming you've got credentials configured to use it), you can do these two things with these two commands, respsectively:

   ```
   aws2 s3api get-bucket-location --bucket bucketnamehere
   ```

   ```
   aws2 s3api list-objects --bucket bucketnamehere
   ```
3. For each object, make a HEAD request to a URL like

   https://bucketname.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/objectname

   with *bucketname*, *us-east-1*, and *objectname* respectively replaced with your bucket name, the actual name of the bucket's region, and your object name.

   To do this from the Unix command line with Curl, do

   ```
   curl -I https://bucketname.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/objectname
   ```

An example implementation of the logic above in Python using Boto 3 and Requests:

```py
from typing import Iterator
import boto3
import requests

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
all_buckets = [
    bucket_dict['Name'] for bucket_dict in
    s3.list_buckets()['Buckets']
]

def list_objs(bucket: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    """
    Generator yielding all object names in the bucket. Potentially requires
    multiple requests for large buckets since list_objects is capped at 1000
    objects returned per call.
    """
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket)
    while True:
        if 'Contents' not in response:
            # Happens if bucket is empty
            return
        for obj_dict in response['Contents']:
            yield obj_dict['Key']
            last_key = obj_dict['Key']
        if response['IsTruncated']:
            response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, StartAfter=last_key)
        else:
            return

def is_public(bucket: str, region: str, obj: str) -> bool:
    url = f'https://{bucket}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{obj}'
    resp = requests.head(url)
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        return True
    elif resp.status_code == 403:
        return False
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Unexpected HTTP code {resp.status_code} from {url}')

for bucket in all_buckets:
    region = s3.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket)['LocationConstraint']
    for obj in list_objs(bucket):
        if is_public(bucket, region, obj):
            print(f'{bucket}/{obj} is public')
```

Be aware that this takes about a second per object, which is... not ideal, if you have a lot of stuff in S3. I don't know of a faster alternative, though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the name of the bucket or list of buckets into "buckets.list" file & run the bash script below.

The script supports unlimited(!) number of objects as it uses pagination.

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX_ITEMS=100
PAGE_SIZE=100

for BUCKET in $(cat buckets.list);
do
    OBJECTS=$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $BUCKET --max-items=$MAX_ITEMS --page-size=$PAGE_SIZE 2>/dev/null)
    e1=$?

    if [[ "OBJECTS" =~ "Could not connect to the endpoint URL" ]]; then
        echo "Could not connect to the endpoint URL!"
        echo -e "$BUCKET" "$OBJECT" "Could not connect to the endpoint URL" >> errors.log
    fi

    NEXT_TOKEN=$(echo $OBJECTS | jq -r '.NextToken')

    while [[ "$NEXT_TOKEN" != "" ]]
    do
        OBJECTS=$(aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket $BUCKET --max-items=$MAX_ITEMS --page-size=$PAGE_SIZE --starting-token $NEXT_TOKEN | jq -r '.Contents | .[].Key' 2>/dev/null)
        for OBJECT in $OBJECTS;
        do
            ACL=$(aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket $BUCKET --key $OBJECT --query "Grants[?Grantee.URI=='http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers']" --output=text 2>/dev/null)
            e2=$?
            if [[ "$ACL" =~ "Could not connect to the endpoint URL" ]]; then
                echo "Could not connect to the endpoint URL!"
                echo -e "$BUCKET" "$OBJECT" "Could not connect to the endpoint URL" >> errors.log
            fi

            if [[ ! "$ACL" == ""  ]] && [[ $e1 == 0 ]] && [[ $e2 == 0 ]]; then
                echo -e "$BUCKET" "$OBJECT" "Public object!!!" "$ACL"
                echo -e "$BUCKET" "$OBJECT" "$ACL" >> public-objects.log
            else
                echo -e "$BUCKET" "$OBJECT" "not public"
            fi
        done
    done
done
```

Answer (score -1):

After some time spending with AWS CLI can tell you that the best approach for that is to sync, mv or cp files with permissions under structured prefixes 
Permission – Specifies the granted permissions, and can be set to read, readacl, writeacl, or full.

For example `aws s3 sync . s3://my-bucket/path --acl public-read`

Then under needed prefix list all those objects.